# Parts of mesh missing after exporting to OBJ

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to export a model I made to OBJ.
After this I'm opening it with Outfit Studio, a tool to make a NIF file to get it into Skyrim.
Somehow the exported model misses some parts when I open it in Outfit Studio.

[image]

I removed double vertices and recalculated normals.
This is how it looks in Blender:

[image]

I'm kinda lost, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix it myself, the problem were those huge Ngons created by the Bevel.
This works fine in Blender but seems to be a problem in Outfit Studio/Nifskope.

Now I created faces with 4 vertices like this and it works fine:

[image]